# How to convert for loop to lapply in R?

Tags: r

I have for loop for reading files in directory and doing some computations on them.
I want to replace my for loop with lapply to be able use parralel package to make my compuation parralel.
would someone help me to convert this for loop to lapply ?

```
for (filename in dir(data.dir))
{


    filename = paste(data.dir,filename,sep="/")
    dfr=read.table(filename,header=TRUE)

    if (ncol(dfr) > 1)
    {
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
files <- list.files(path="...") # fill in the path, if you only want say .txt files then add pattern="txt"
data.list <- lapply(files, function(x) read.table(x,header=T))
```

You now have a list of data.frames

```
res <- lapply(data.list, function(x) {if (ncol(x) > 1) {....}})
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace `for (filename in dir(data.dir)) {...}` with `lapply(dir(data.dir), function(filename) {...})`

Presumably you'll need to add some kind of return value in there, but it's not clear from your code what the output of your loop is.